# PyCharm no AutoCompleting / TypeHints global variable

Tags: python, pycharm, global-variables

I want to edit a variable that is global but PyCharm does not give me any hints about what operation I can do.

Here is some example code I've written:

```
def run_game_loop():
    global g
    for i in range(0, g.rounds_total):
        g.new_round() # no auto-complete
```

I do not know what to do? Did I config my PyCharm wrong or am I not supposed to use global like that?

Comment: `g` isn't assigned to anything. What autocomplete are you expecting, beyond things like `ifn` and `ifnn`?

Comment: `g` is created in an other file but it is still global and I want to access the variable from this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It adds some bulk, but you can add a type hinted line:

```
def run_game_loop():
    global g
    g: YOUR_TYPE

    for i in range(0, g.rounds_total):
        g.new_round()
```

Where `YOUR_TYPE` is the type of `g`. It should now know what the type is, and should be able to make better suggestions.

Comment: I now reallized that I can use # type: int for example

Comment: @Kriang_0 I think comment hints are deprecated unless you're using an old version of Python, but yes, they'll work as well.